# Change the size of an image inside border on click in c#

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I make an image inside button to make it bigger when I click it using `Width` and `Height`.

My Button XAML code is this:

```
<Button x:Name="Input2" Grid.Row="0" MouseEnter="Input2_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Input2_MouseLeave" Click="Input2_Click" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="{x:Null}">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                        <Image Source= "C:\input.png"
                           Width="40" 
                           Height="40"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

`Input2.Height` - Change the size of the button, not the image inside it.

My C# code:

```
private void Input2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // What to do here?
}
```

Comment: How would the size be reset? Or do you want to keep the resized image after the first click? What you probably want is a Trigger on the IsPressed property of the Button.

Comment: @Clemens I will reset it, I just need to know how can I change the size...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of attaching a Click event handler, better use a Trigger on the Button's `IsPressed` property:

```
<Button>
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Border>
                <Image x:Name="image" Width="40" Height="40" Source="C:\input.png"/>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="image" Property="Width" Value="50"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="image" Property="Height" Value="50"/>
                </Trigger> 
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Comment: How can I change it back?

Comment: It changes back automatically, as soon as the Button's IsPressed property goes back to false.

Comment: I don't want this automatically to change back, I want on my terms.

Comment: So how exactly are you going to reset the size?

Comment: If I did it on C# I can do the opposite with some terms

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Will there be another click? Are you sure you don't actually want a ToggleButton?

Comment: I don't want a toggle button, There will be a click in some places that reset the size of the button

Comment: So these Buttons are kind of "selected items" in a list? You should perhaps edit your question with some details about what you're actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest solution will be to add x:Name="input2Image" to the Image element, and enlarge the image using that name, like that:

```
<Button x:Name="Input2" Grid.Row="0" MouseEnter="Input2_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Input2_MouseLeave" Click="Input2_Click" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="{x:Null}">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                    <Image x:Name="Input2Image" Source= "C:\input.png"
                       Width="40" 
                       Height="40"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
```

And:

```
private void Input2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Input2Image.Height = 80;
    this.Input2Image.Width = 80;
}
```

This should work, but you might consider start using Bindings and the MVVM pattern, to maximize the power of WPF.

Comment: @Clemens Still, he could have used a converter or trigger that will represent the data on the view side, and still have a property on the model side.